# Cursor movement history in Vim

Tags: vim, history, cursor, undo

How can I restore cursor position in Vim as it was before scrolling, selecting or PgUp/PgDn?

I'm tired of searching where I was before I scrolled up to look something at the top.

Are there something like "Prev cursor position" and "Next cursor position" commands (like 'u' and 'R' for regular undo/redo)?

Example: Looking somewhere in the middle of the source file (no editing), then jumping to the top (`1G`) then failing to find where you was before that. Of course, no marks set. (I know that I can use ":sp" to view several places simultaneously).

**Update.** The question is still open, I have received a follow-up:

```
The answerers didn't understand your question and the answers were too weak of a solution. c-o & c-i don't work for movements.
If I understood correctly, I find that your question was un-answered and that you were looking for a solution for a scenario like this:
As I am vim beginner I frequently do incorrect movements and actions and would like to undo them as though I had never pressed anything, returning to my previous editing location before I started messing up.
```

So, are there any standard or non-standard (involving patches to Vim or Vim extensions) ways to make it remember the cursor movement history?

Answer (score 10):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> goes back in jump list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> goes forward in jump list

additionally i would consider to set a mark via <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> and when done with scrolling press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>.

Comment: OK, Ctrl+o jumps me to the place where I was editing. How to just to the place where I was _looking_? I enter "1G" to jump to the beginning and don't know how to jump back (I wasn't editing). Of course mark is not set and I haven't used ":sp".

Comment: @Vi: no, ctrl-o jumps to where your last jump was (jump list). g; goes where you edited last

Comment: 1. "vim initrd.txt". 2. 5 times PgDn, 10 times Down. 3. Hold PgUp until hit the top. 4. Ctrl+o?  No, It's just jumped to the top. 5. Crtl+o again? It opened some other file... I don't understand what exactly Ctrl+o does, but it doesn't just undo the last cursor movement command.

Comment: i know, it is using the "jump list" .. :help jumps ... thats why i meant, probably a good idea to use the markers. if you want to jump around in your file and you want to go back to THAT place you started: set a mark, jump around and then come back with ''.

Comment: So I can't make Vim replay text and cursor scroll history backwards (I also expected it will handle mouse scrolling in gvim), right? I expected that while holding Ctrl+O is see my text movements reversed, finishing at just opened file positioned in the beginning.